Runtime Upgrade with Block Time Change Stops Block Production
I am performing a runtime upgrade for my Substrate-based blockchain, specifically changing the block time from 6 seconds to 1 second. The upgrade is executed successfully using the set_code function, but after the upgrade, the chain stops producing blocks. The logs show the following error:
2024-07-18 12:36:06 panicked at /Users/sergeygerodes/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/851c824/substrate/frame/aura/src/lib.rs:139:21:
Slot must increase
2024-07-18 12:36:06 Proposing failed: Import failed: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm unreachable instruction executed
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
0: 0x1dc389 - g6_solo_runtime.wasm!rust_begin_unwind
1: 0xdc6d - g6_solo_runtime.wasm!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h6ae54cc3978c3bfd
2: 0x172d2b - g6_solo_runtime.wasm!<pallet_aura::pallet::Pallet<T> as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnInitialize<<<<T as frame_system::pallet::Config>::Block as sp_runtime::traits::HeaderProvider>::HeaderT as sp_runtime::traits::Header>::Number>>::on_initialize::h1d9385cd97f8b305
3: 0xe5d0d - g6_solo_runtime.wasm!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::initialize_block::hfe44e3e7eebc357d
4: 0x145b3b - g6_solo_runtime.wasm!Core_initialize_block

Context:
•   Normal runtime upgrades work fine without any issues.
•   The issue occurs specifically after changing the block time.

Is there a way to change blocktime in an upgrade?

The problem is that your node side isn't aware of the slot time changing. This means that it still uses the old slot time of 6s to calculate the slot and this slot is then rejected by the runtime.
A simple fix should be to restart your collators to pick up the new slot duration. However, you can also change your node like here to make it work. Basically you need to ensure that you don't fetch slot_duration only at startup.
